# #<ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)> in admin.rb:32:in `kick'

Tags: ruby, arguments

I've got a problem with ruby, in the first file, client.rb, I have the code

```
# Kicks a user from chat. Requires mod rights (or above)
# @param [String] user
def kick(user)
  post(:msgType => :command, :command => :kick, :userToKick => user)
  end
```

and in the code that has script errors is

```
match /^kick/, :method => :kick

# @param [User] user
# @param [String] target
def kick(user, target)
  if user.is? :mod
    @client.kick(target)
  end
end
```

and ive got the error on the title
Which is the problem?? I've tried everything..

Comment: What is target? Do you want kick to take one or two arguments?

Comment: its suposed to usea two arguments, I mean, its for a chat, target would be the person to be kicked, user its yourself, but... Im not sure what I'm doing wrong or how to solve it

Comment: Two arguments... Target would be the person in the chat to kick, user, well, the person perfoming the command.

Comment: Is @client correctly initialized  in your admin.rb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want: `match /^kick (.*)/, :method => :kick`, not `match /^kick/, :method => :kick`. Every capture group in the regex passed match is passed as an argument to the specified method - without a capture group, only `user` will be passed.

[See example here](https://github.com/sactage/chatbot-rb/blob/master/plugins/admin.rb#L8)